# Android L - android.graphics.outline

Tags: android, outline, android-5.0-lollipop

According to the android developer page for the developer preview of L, it's possible to use the **Outline** class & define outlines for view's to display the shadows in the correct way.
(http://developer.android.com/preview/material/views-shadows.html#shadows)

In my case, the "L"-sdk I use, didn't found it. Therefore I couldn't import and use the class.

According to the test project, stored in **sdk/samples/android-L/ui/views/Elevation/ElevationDrag** this class should be stored in "android.graphics.outline", but even in this project it can't be located correctly.

Is this feature not implemented in the developer preview yet or did I missed something?

Comment: No problems finding the class here. Are you seeing other L -features properly, i.e can you use View.setTranslationZ(float) and such?

Comment: @harism I just tried this. Same for that one, it can't be found, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.

It's a bug in android studio. I just added manually the import to my activity:

```
import android.graphics.Outline
```

It will be shown as error, but it can compile & run.
I hope they will fix this soon.

EDIT: I created an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72788&q=android%20studio%20android%20l&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

It looks like, they're working on it.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem than you but your answer it didn't work for me, I am trying to import

`import android.graphics.outline;`

And de output is:

`Error:(7, 24) error: cannot find symbol class outline`

The `build.gradle`seems to be well configurated with the 
`compileSdkVersion 'android-L'`
sentence

** **Fixed**

the right import is: `import android.graphics.Outline;`