# Android: cannot use graphics Outline

Tags: android, android-studio, outline-view

I want to create some sort of custom "FAB" Button, therefore I am using the `android.graphics.Outline` class, but I am not able to import it. If I try it, Android Studio shows the following message:

```
error: cannot find symbol class Outline
```

The following tools are installed:

- Android Studio 0.8.2
- Android SDK 19

I found a bug report regarding Android Studio, Outline and the newest SDL (Preview L), but I also get a similar error, when I try to build it by calling `./gradlew build`.

```
MainActivity.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
import android.graphics.Outline;
                       ^
  symbol:   class Outline
  location: package android.graphics
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476179/android-l-android-graphics-outline says it is a bug in Android Studio

Comment: Yes, this is the bug i mentioned. But I ALSO get this error, if I call gradle with the console! So it's not only a AS bug...